# Difference between two sentences: 魚が好きな人 and 人は魚が好きだ

Tags: word-order, は-and-が

> 魚が好きな人。
>
> 人は魚が好きだ。

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: If you are still trying to figure out the subject particles は and が as you were in a previous question, (if I may voice a controversial opinion) I recommend that you stay away from any example that involves the words 好き or 嫌い because apart from the most basic constructions, the particle usage for those two words is hard to grasp for the learner. (That said, your second sentence is what I consider a basic construction.)

Answer (score 5):

> 魚が好きな人。

It's not a sentence, there is no predicate. It's a noun phrase meaning "a person who likes fish", or if the general subject where this expression appeared is a comparison between different animal species (including human) "fish-liking human(kind)".

> 人は魚が好きだ。

This on the other hand is a full sentence. "Human(kind) like fish".

Comment: How would i make it a full sentence?

Comment: What do you mean by "*how would you make it a full sentence*"? You don't say **what** you want to say. You need to add a predicate and maybe other phrases to give it meaning.

Comment: You need a verb to make it into a clause

Answer (score 1):

I agree with macraf. They have a few differences.

> 魚が好きな人

This is a noun phrase because there is no predicate (述語).

> 人は魚が好きだ。

This is a sentence because it ends with a predicate, na-adjective 好きだ.